# How to Create Show/Hide button when Looping in React

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks, next.js, uibutton

I am working on a development site and am having an issue. The issue is that I am looping over the data file in order to create some project cards. Each project card has a show more/show less button to display/hide card descriptions.

My problem is that the current setup is mapping over the data and causing it so that whenever one gets clicked, all three either open or close simultaneously. Please help me to fix this issue. Relevant code is shown below:

Data example:

```
{
name: "Hot in the Biscuit",
id: "3a34",
image: "/images/bonnie.jpg",
description: "A multi-page front-end business website for a local restaurant in Koh Samui, Thailand. Custom design built with vanilla JavaScript, HTML and CSS.",
link: "https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com",
date: "2021",
github: "https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
},
```

Hero file where Showcase Component is rendered:

```
               <h1>Featured Projects</h1>
             <div>
             <Showcase/>
             </div>
```

Showcase where cards are created (UNNECCESSARY CODE REMOVED - classes and image):

```
const Showcase = () => {
    const {readMore, setReadMore} = useContext(HeroContext)
    const {toggleMenu} = useContext(NavbarContext)
    return(
        <>
  {showcase.map((item) => {
    const {id, name, image, link, github, description, date} = item;
      return (
        <div key={id}>
        <div>
       {!toggleMenu &&
        <div>
        <Image/>
        </div>
       }
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>{name} | {date}</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>{ readMore[id] ?   <-- THIS IS WHERE YOU NEED AN ID
                    description :
                    `${description.substring(0, 100)}...`
                    } <button key={id} onClick={() => setReadMore(!readMore)}>{readMore[id] ? "Show Less" : "Show More"}</button>
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div>
            <a href={github}>
                <FiGithub/>
            </a>
                <a href={link}>
                <h4 >See For Yourself! &#8594;</h4>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      )
  })}   
  </>
    )   
}
export default Showcase
```

So I just need some help on figuring out how to set it up so that each button knows which card is being clicked and only that button open. Thank you very much for helping me. I appreciate your time and help immensely.

Bodi

Answer (score 0):

You should update the `HeroContext` state to hold a reference to the `id`s that are shown/hidden.

Example:

```
const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState({});

const readMoreToggler = (id) => setReadMore(state => ({
  ...state,
  [id]: !state[id], // <-- toggle boolean value
}));

// context value
{
  readmore,
  setReadMore: readMoreToggler, // pass readMoreToggler as setReadMore
}
```

...

```
const { readMore, setReadMore } = useContext(HeroContext);

...

{showcase.map((item) => {
  const {id, name, image, link, github, description, date} = item;
  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
      <div>
        ...
        <div>
          <h4>
            {readMore[id] // <-- check by id if toggled true|false
              ? description
              : `${description.substring(0, 100)}...`
            }
            <button
              onClick={() => setReadMore(id)} // <-- pass id to toggle
            >
              {readMore[id] ? "Show Less" : "Show More"} // <-- check by id if toggled true|false
            </button>
          </h4>
        </div>
      <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Comment: Hello Drew, I am really appreciative of your generous help and offering of time. I never expected to receive an answer so quickly. I look forward to being as helpful as you are someday, sooner than later I hope. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi Drew - I am sorry to bother you but could you please clarify if I should keep my original useState:    const {readMore, setReadMore} = useContext(HeroContext) and then add your suggestion as a second state to hold an empty object? 

Your naming switches between mine and yours but then you named a function as readMore and now I am confused because that is the name of my original useState value, but then you import setReadMore too. When I remove my readMore/setReadMore and try to only use your setup I am unsuccessful. Any additional clarification would be appreciated. My apologies again.

Comment: @BodiAugustus No worries. And sorry if the changes were a bit confusing. I did that because you effectively only want to expose out the `readmore` state (*now an object with id keys*) and a `setReadMore` function to update the state. The difference was made to keep the context  API nearly the same, i.e. state and updater function, but now the provider maintains control over how state is updated. You could just as easily keep your naming, call the handler function something else and provide *that* instead of your `setReadMore` state updater. Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm sorry Drew I spoke too soon - I want to whittle this down, am I correct in the assumption that **setReadMore** is really supposed to be **setReadMoreState**? If that is not the case, can you please also tell me where setReadMore is supposed to come from? From my state? Should  I have two states for this, a false and an empty object, or just your empty object state shown in your example? Sorry for all the questions..

Comment: @BodiAugustus I'll update my answer and hopefully it will be made more clear.

Comment: @BodiAugustus Keep the `const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState({});`, and when exporting the context value use `readMoreToggler` instead of `setReadMore` function.

Comment: Words fail to express my appreciation for your patience, time, and help Drew. Thank you very much. For anyone in the future with this similar issue, once you have the id you need to also apply it to the description - check my initial posting for the edit with just the id's added to show you what I mean. Thanks again to Drew.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you split showcase item to a new component.

```
const ShowCaseItem = ({ data }) => {
  const { toggleMenu } = useContext(NavbarContext)
  const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false)
  const { id, name, image, link, github, description, date } = data;
  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <div>
        {!toggleMenu &&
          <div>
            <Image />
          </div>
        }
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>{name} | {date}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>{readMore ?
            description :
            `${description.substring(0, 100)}...`
          } <button key={id} onClick={() => setReadMore(!readMore)}>{readMore ? "Show Less" : "Show More"}</button>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href={github}>
            <FiGithub />
          </a>
          <a href={link}>
            <h4 >See For Yourself! &#8594;</h4>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
const Showcase = () => {
  const { readMore, setReadMore } = useContext(HeroContext)
  return (
    <>
      {showcase.map((item) => <ShowCaseItem data={item} />)}
    </>
  )
}
export default Showcase
```